# use pushy lib push to voip but the iphone cann't accept the message

Tags: java, ios, notifications, voip, pushy

1,iphone app use pushkit receive the Notification;
2,java server use pushy to send Notification;

in java server,the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.turo</groupId>
  <artifactId>pushy</artifactId>
  <version>0.13.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
  <artifactId>netty-tcnative-boringssl-static</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.25.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

use java code like this

```
final ApnsClient apnsClient = new ApnsClientBuilder()
    .setApnsServer(ApnsClientBuilder.DEVELOPMENT_APNS_HOST)
    .setClientCredentials(new File("/path/to/certificate.p12"), "p12-file-password")
    .build();
```

other code like this: https://github.com/relayrides/pushy

set  .p12,token,bundleid and the Notification context then run sucess

after run log like this

```
2019-11-20 16:09:55.372 [main] INFO  com.turo.pushy.apns.ApnsClientBuilder - Native SSL provider is available; will use native provider.  
2019-11-20 16:09:56.601 [main] INFO  com.citic.controller.push.PushController - token :351bf5a20a6fce9f5b6c17c8f3090d0c659818b8097e6bdfb3ee02bc54d84957title :aabody :hi bb  

2019-11-20 16:09:58.263 [main] INFO  com.citic.controller.push.PushController - 1Push notification accepted by APNs gateway.  
2019-11-20 16:09:58.264 [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] INFO  com.citic.controller.push.PushController - 4pushNotificationResponse.getRejectionReason() { }
```

I use voip.p12 and the rigth config message but the (iphone)ios app cannot Receive any thing

Another way I send apns Notification,my ios app can get it;

note: apns and voip is Different certificate, it's all right;

my problem

how to check or debug the Notification Arrive to somewhere;

where the code wrong ?

pls help,so many many many thanks

Comment: bundleid like this : xxx.xxx.xxx.voip

Comment: Use DEBUG Logging Level instead of INFO

Comment: I don't know witch status is arrive apns or arrive iphone;

Comment: the debug msg like this: https://github.com/lingo169/testweb/blob/master/pushy_voip.log

Comment: @lingo.in `xxx.xxx.xxx.voip ` saved me. I was having  `DeviceTokenNotForTopic` error. Thank you.